# How to lookup an array of strings to match a value in a column?

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, postgresql-9.4

I have a master table holding the list of possible street types:

```
CREATE TABLE land.street_type (
  str_type character varying(300)
);

insert into land.street_type values
  ('STREET'),
  ('DRIVE'),
  ('ROAD');
```

I have a table in which address is loaded and I need to parse the string to do a lookup on the master street type to fetch the suburb following the street.

```
CREATE TABLE land.bank_application (
  mailing_address character varying(300)
);

insert into land.bank_application values 
   ('8 115 MACKIE STREET VICTORIA PARK WA 6100 AU'),
   ('69 79 CABBAGE TREE ROAD BAYVIEW NSW 2104 AU'),
   ('17 COWPER DRIVE CAMDEN SOUTH NSW 2570 AU');
```

Expected output:

```
VICTORIA PARK
BAYVIEW
CAMDEN SOUTH
```

Any PostgreSQL technique to look up a array of values against a table column and fetch the data following the matching word?

If I'm able to fetch the data present after the street type, then I can remove the last 3 fields state, postal code and country code from that to identify the suburb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query does what you ask for using [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-posix-regexp):

```
SELECT substring(b.mailing_address, ' ' || s.str_type || ' (.*) \D+ \d+ \D+$') AS suburb
FROM   bank_application b
JOIN   street_type s ON b.mailing_address ~ (' ' || s.str_type || ' ');
```

The regexp `' (.*) \D+ \d+ \D+$'` explained step by step:

.. leading space (the assumed delimiter, else something like 'BROAD' would match 'ROAD')
`(.*)` .. capturing parentheses with 0-n arbitrary characters: `.*`
`\D+`  .. 1-n non-digits
`\d+`  .. 1-n digits
`$` .. end of string

[The manual on  ***POSIX Regular Expressions***.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-posix-regexp)

But it relies on the given format of `mailing_address`. Is the format of your strings that reliable?

And suburbs can have words like 'STREET' etc. as part of their name - the approach seems unreliable on principal.

BTW, there is *no* array involved, you seem to be confusing arrays and sets.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, it works for me. i'm trying to understand ' (.*) \D+ \d+ \D+$', but unable to.

Comment: @HarinathArasu: I added some explanation and a link to details in the manual.